# Email delivery fails for email which does not exist

Tags: email

I want to know what happens if an email delivery fails because email account does not exist and if someone creates same account later then what happens to failed mail delivery. Does email server keeps trying to send that email or it tries only one time?

Comment: I expect theeror message will tell it what to do. If the address does not exist, why would it send more times?

Comment: http://www.penpublishing.com/Support/EmailErrors/UnderstandingEmailErrors/#userunknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail Daemon will return the e-mail when the recipient can't be found. It will not keep trying to send that e-mail if the account is made later.

Answer (score 2):

When the receiving SMTP server reports that the account does not exist the mail is "bounced" immediately and the sender is informed. No further actions are carried out unless the sender resends the mail.